# Go to type definition is not working for objects with Generics in types Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have some code like this:

```
type GA<s extends string> = { [name in s]: number };
type A = 'somePropName';

export const b: GA<A> = {
  somePropName: 10,
};


const c = b.somePropName;
```

Everything is ok with types, c became number. But, if we will try to "Go To Definition" on somePropName in vscode (or somewhere else) — it will not be possible. It is strange, cause there is a reference from b.somePropName to somePropName in "b".

How can I implement the same logic with working "Go To Definition"? Is it possible? What the limitation?

By the way, you could try to "Go to definition" on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html with the same code. And it won't work too, like in vscode. So, it is not a problem of vscode.
Here is a [link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20GA%3Cs%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bname%20in%20s%5D%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20'somePropName'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20b%3A%20GA%3CA%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20somePropName%3A%2010%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20b.somePropName%3B)

Comment: Where are you running go to type definition? On `somePropName`?

Comment: Yes. I will add it to description.